# How do I perform one-step transformation in python?

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I would like to perform transformation for this example data set.
I have here four pairs of adjustment points and want to transform given point coordinates from primary system to secondary system according to adjustment.

```
primary_system1 = (3531820.440, 1174966.736, 5162268.086)
primary_system2 = (3531746.800, 1175275.159, 5162241.325)
primary_system3 = (3532510.182, 1174373.785, 5161954.920)
primary_system4 = (3532495.968, 1175507.195, 5161685.049)

secondary_system1 = (6089665.610, 3591595.470, 148.810)
secondary_system2 = (6089633.900, 3591912.090, 143.120)
secondary_system3 = (6089088.170, 3590826.470, 166.350)
secondary_system4 = (6088672.490, 3591914.630, 147.440)

#transform this point
x = 3532412.323 
y = 1175511.432
z = 5161677.111<br>
```

eventually, how do I compute helmert transformation parameters, shifts, rotations and scale factor?

EDIT
at the moment I try to average translation for x, y and z axis using each of the four pairs of points like:

```
#x axis
xt1 =  secondary_system1[0] - primary_system1[0]           
xt2 =  secondary_system2[0] - primary_system2[0]
xt3 =  secondary_system3[0] - primary_system3[0]
xt4 =  secondary_system4[0] - primary_system4[0]

xt = (xt1+xt2+xt3+xt4)/4    #averaging
```

...and so on for y and z axis

```
#y axis
yt1 =  secondary_system1[1] - primary_system1[1]           
yt2 =  secondary_system2[1] - primary_system2[1]
yt3 =  secondary_system3[1] - primary_system3[1]
yt4 =  secondary_system4[1] - primary_system4[1]

yt = (yt1+yt2+yt3+yt4)/4    #averaging

#z axis
zt1 =  secondary_system1[2] - primary_system1[2]           
zt2 =  secondary_system2[2] - primary_system2[2]
zt3 =  secondary_system3[2] - primary_system3[2]
zt4 =  secondary_system4[2] - primary_system4[2]

zt = (zt1+zt2+zt3+zt4)/4    #averaging
```

Is it right way?

Comment: Can you use proj4, Gdal, or any other library to do the transformation from ESPG_X to ESPG_Y?

Comment: I would like to perform something like site calibration, where parameters for secondary system are unknown as it is local system.

Comment: The question, as stated, is not answerable: with only four pairs of control points, you cannot hope to estimate seven independent parameters (three shift values, three rotation values, and a scale value).

Comment: @whuber, yes you can. In fact you can do it with two 3-space points and a z-coordinate, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmert_transformation. The attachment to this post: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2010-March/024495.html  even provides some Python code that produces the Helmert parameters.

Comment: @Mersey Thank you for that correction!  Yes, you and Wikipedia are right: four points determines a rigid reference frame, so there should be a unique Euclidean transformation from one set of four points to another.

Comment: @daikini -- See whuber's answer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19963/how-to-translate-coordinates-on-the-earth

Answer (score 2):

There is a [python wrapper](http://pyproj.googlecode.com/svn-history/r174/trunk/README.html) for the proj4 library. [Proj4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) is a commonly used library for projecting data from one system to another.

Whatever system you do use, it will most likely take the point information in the form `(lon, lat)` or `(y,x)`. Just something to be aware of - I've made this mistake in the past.

(I'm not familiar with the helmert transformation part of your question.)

Comment: Yes, I know proj4 module but I am not sure if there's possibility to transform between undefined coordinate systems.

Comment: ah ok. What do you mean `transform between undefined coordinate systems`? Does a coordinate system not have to have some sort of descriptor, by definition?

Comment: I mean that I have no parameters of second coordinate system, only adjustment.

Comment: Not sure if this book is of any help: http://books.google.com/books?id=zvPNNzMM7uwC&pg=PA345&lpg=PA345&dq=transformation+adjustment+projection&source=bl&ots=po3Yc6v5B7&sig=UJq7x_KrUrF7L0qAYBOL2ZgKZC4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b3sTT5TDNYL50gG446WyAw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=transformation%20adjustment%20projection&f=false