# Moving a shape around the earth while maintaining the proper projection

Tags: leaflet, coordinate-system, d3

What is the transformation needed to be taken on every data point of a shape to 
rotate that shape around the globe.

I'm trying to figure out the math behind this kind of transformation so I can create something similar to this using leaflet and d3 https://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/poly/puzzledrag.html

**Edit:** To be clear, I am looking to achieve this using leaflet, D3, and javascript not desktop GIS software. My end product will a function that takes a point `(lat,lng)` shifts it by an amount `(shift_lat,shift_lng)` and returns `(new_lat,new_lng)`

Comment: An Affine transformation should do it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation it requires more parameters in 3d. It accounts for scale and rotation without distorting the original shape.

Comment: maybe I misundersand you, but the shown example has a mercator projection, on which several polygons are drawn at different locations. a poly consists of a number of points. each point has a specific latitude and longitude, which is projected. when you move the poly to the north, each point has a higher latitude, which when projected results in larger area. moving to the ecuator means each point has a lower latitude, resulting after projection in a smaller area.

Comment: @Kurt I'm looking to move the poly north in unprojected space and then project it in Mercator. It is expected that this transformation will change the pixel area of the shape. What I'm looking for here is the way—for instance—to move a poly north 20 degrees.

Comment: The most elegant method with a full-featured GIS is simply to change the *metadata* for the shape! Declare it to have the same kind of projection, but change it to an oblique aspect (such as an oblique Mercator if the original shape is in Mercator coordinates). Ask the GIS to reproject this shape--whose *coordinates* have not changed--into the original projection. Done!

Comment: @whuber I need to do the transformation on the fly based on the interaction of a user so using GIS software for the transformation is out

Comment: Then please edit your question to include that important restriction, because not everyone will read through all the comments.

Comment: This question now appears to be a special case of [How to Translate Coordinates...](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19963). The formulas are given in the first three code blocks of [my answer there](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20001/664).

Answer (score -1):

the math will depend on the projection and what you want to preserve.

A generic solution would consist in computing the Lat/Long coordinates of your points, then you simply add the value of your shift to each coordinates, and you finally reproject in your initial projected coordinate system. For pure East-West rotation, there is no distortion. For North-east translation, this will squeeze your object.

If you want to preserve the horizontal distances, you must therefore adjust the longitude based on the change in latitude

long2 = long_c + (long1 - long_c)*( cos(lat1)/cos(lat2) )

where long_c is the longitude of the center of your pixel, lat1 and lat2 are the latitude before and after the shift (in other word, lat2 = lat1+shift).

Comment: Addition of coordinates in lat-lon does not constitute the requested rotation except for rotations around the Earth's axis. The adjustment of longitude you suggest will not work.